# ¿Cómo crear Jpanel dinámicamente?

Tags: netbeans, java-swing

por favor necesito ayuda sobre esto...
Tengo un Jframe que contiene un jpanel dentro... mi idea es que mediante un arraylist de botones que se cargará al ejecutar este jframe, se muestren en el jpanel, pero solo 3 botones... si llego a tener más de 3 botones, quiero que se encuentre en otro jpanel, pero que estos no esten visibles hasta que de en un botón de "siguiente".
Por ejemplo si tengo 8 botones en mi arraylist, en el panel del frame me debería mostrar los 3 primeros, los 3 siguientes en un segundo panel y los 2 restan en un tercer panel, que solo quiero que recién se vean cuando le de en "siguiente" solo necesito que alguien me ayude en como ir generando esos paneles, ya que mi lista puede tener 'n' elementos y por lo tanto también necesitaría de 'n' paneles dentro del panel que tengo, las posiciones de los botones ya lo tengo todo, solo este problema no más tengo.

Comment: A todo lo que quieras hacer ponele algo de código,  no importa si está bien o mal. Eso dps se cambia, pero almenos mostrar algo de código tuyo y apartir de ahí se trabaja.

Answer (score 1):

Voy a pasarte dos códigos para veas si te sirve alguno con la intención de que encuentres la solución más facilemente.

**El primero:**

Itera sobre una **List** y **separa** en grupos de a tres botones, una vez que lée los tres botones realiza un acción determinada, que en este caso vos tendrías que pensar la lógica extra que sería la creación y adherencia de los mismos a un JPanel al JFrame.

En este caso sólo hize que aparezca una impresión del texto de cada botón por consola.

Para mi es realmente complejo de entender, hasta también de aplicar. Buscar una solución alternativa creo que es una mejor opción.

Una vez que le des Run as java application, observá por la consola el comportamiento de los objetos de la List<>.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel {
    private List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<>();
    private JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Panel() {

        button1 = new JButton("Boton1");
        button2 = new JButton("Boton2");
        button3 = new JButton("Boton3");
        button4 = new JButton("Boton4");
        button5 = new JButton("Boton5");
        button6 = new JButton("Boton6");
        button7 = new JButton("Boton7");
        button8 = new JButton("Boton8");
        button9 = new JButton("Boton9");
        buttons = Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9);

        frame = new JFrame(); // Frame
        panel = new JPanel(); // Panel
        frame.add(panel); // Agregamos el panel al frame

        /* Cominezo de la aplicación del método que itera */
        int startIndex = 0;
        int items = 3;

        while (startIndex < buttons.size()) {
            buttonsByParts(buttons, startIndex, items);
            startIndex += items;

            /* Adherimos en este panel las posiciones 0,1,2 de la List<> */
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                panel.add(buttons.get(i));
            }

        }

        /* Configuración básica */
        frame.setTitle("JTextField");
        frame.setBounds(160, 160, 300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void buttonsByParts(List<JButton> buttons, int startIndex, int items) {

        if (buttons != null && startIndex >= 0 && startIndex < buttons.size()) {

            // recorro desde el indice inicial indicado mientras no haya llegado al final de
            // la lista ni haya impreso la cantidad deseada de elementos
            while (startIndex < buttons.size() && items > 0) {

                // imprimo boton
                System.out.println(buttons.get(startIndex).getText());

                // incremento el indice de recorrida
                startIndex++;

                // decremento la cantidad de items restantes a imprimir
                items--;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();
    }

}
```

**La segunda:**

Me parece más simple de aplicar, no se automatizan las creaciones de JPanel pero es una forma simple de crear un panel a partir de un boton. Si querés crear más paneles que contengan más botones lo unico que tenes que hacer es agregar el código al método addActionListener().

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel {

    private JButton next;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Panel() {

        next = new JButton("Siguiente");
        frame = new JFrame(); // Frame
        panel = new JPanel(); // Panel
        panel.add(next); // Adherimos el boton al panel
        frame.add(panel); // Agregamos el panel al frame

        next.addActionListener(event -> {
            JFrame frame2 = new JFrame();
            frame2.add(newPanel());
            frame2.setBounds(150, 150, 300, 300);
            frame2.setVisible(true);
        });


        /* Configuración básica */
        frame.setTitle("JTextField");
        frame.setBounds(160, 160, 300, 300);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    /* Método inicializador de App */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Creamos el panel con el setVisible() en su constructor */
        Panel p = new Panel();
    }

    /* Creamos un método que devuelva un JPanel armado */ 
    public JPanel newPanel() {
        List<JButton> listButtons = new ArrayList<>();
        JButton button1 = new JButton("boton1");
        JButton button2 = new JButton("boton2");
        JButton button3 = new JButton("boton3");
        listButtons = Arrays.asList(button1, button2, button3);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        for (int i = 0; i < listButtons.size(); i++) {
            panel.add(listButtons.get(i));
        }

        return panel;
    }

}
```